# Uno Spin; going out using a Spin card

Tags: uno

According to the Spin Uno instructions, if the last card played is a Spin card, the next player must spin the wheel and that action must be resolved so that any cards drawn or discarded also affect the points totaled.

Notice the part that states "...so that any cards drawn or discarded also affect points totaled."  This tells me that if the person spinning the wheel lands on Almost Uno, then they discard all but their last two cards and only the points from the last two cards count.

If my opponent's last card is a Spin card, then I must spin the wheel and that action MUST be resolved.  So, my spin lands on Trade Hands.  That action MUST be resolved.  Does that mean my opponent has to take my hand, which resolves the action, and what happens to those points assuming the scoring method used is getting "caught" with points in your hand?

My opinion is that those points count against my opponent.  My opponent chose to use a Spin card as their last card, which required me to spin the wheel.  My spin landed on Trade Hands and the rules state I MUST resolve that action.  I have to trade hands with my opponent for that action to be RESOLVED; therefore, my opponent gets my remaining cards and I get no cards from them as they used the Spin card as their last card.  That means my opponent gets "caught" with those points.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

First let's look at the normal rules. The [rules](http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/j3719-0920.pdf) for scoring state that:

> The first player to get rid of their cards receives points for cards left in all of players' hands

If a player gets rid of all their cards first, they will be the scoring player even if they end up with cards and someone else does not.

The rules do **not** say that cards in your own hand count against you.

The rules specify "all of players' hands" and do **not** exclude yourself.

**Thus you score points normally from any cards in your own hand at the end of the round.** This statement is true in either variant.

In the "getting caught" variant, you only count the cards in your hand. If you have cards in your hand for any reason, they will count against you.